# Python split string by pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have strings like `"aaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc"`.
The number of the chars can differ and sometimes there can be dash inside the string, like `"aaaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc"`.

Is there any smart way to either split it `"aaaaa"`,`"bbbbbbbbbbbbbb"`,`"ccccccccccc"` and get the indices of were it is split or just get the indices, without looping through every string? If the dash is between to patterns it can end up either in the left or right one as long it is always handled the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regular expression `MatchObject` results include indices of the match. What remains is to match repeating characters:

```
import re

repeat = re.compile(r'(?P<start>[a-z])(?P=start)+-?')
```

would match only if a given letter character (`a`-`z`) is repeated at least once:

```
>>> for match in repeat.finditer("aaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc"):
...     print match.group(), match.start(), match.end()
... 
aaaaa 0 5
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb 5 19
ccccccccccc 19 30
```

The [`.start()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) and [`.end()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end) methods on the match result give you the exact positions in the input string.

Dashes are included in the matches, but not non-repeating characters:

```
>>> for match in repeat.finditer("a-bb-cccccccc"):
...     print match.group(), match.start(), match.end()
... 
bb- 2 5
cccccccc 5 13
```

If you want the `a-` part to be a match, simply replace the `+` with a `*` multiplier:

```
repeat = re.compile(r'(?P<start>[a-z])(?P=start)*-?')
```

Comment: How could I keep the dashes?
So for example "aaaaa-","bbbbbbbbbbbbbb","ccccccccccc".

Comment: @Fritz: Sorry, I thought you didn't want them. On re-reading, I see that you do. I included them with the preceding letters.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I guess I should really look deeper into regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

What about using `itertools.groupby`?

```
>>> s = 'aaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc'
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [''.join(v) for k,v in groupby(s)]
['aaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'ccccccccccc']
```

This will put the `-` as their own substrings which could easily be filtered out.

```
>>> s = 'aaaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbbbb-ccccccccccc'
>>> [''.join(v) for k,v in groupby(s) if k != '-']
['aaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'ccccccccccc']
```

Comment: Can you think of a nice way to get the indices too?  The best I can think of offhand is `grouped = [(k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby(enumerate(s), key=lambda x: x[1])]; [(k, g[0][0], g[-1][0]) for k,g in grouped]`.  In python 3 I guess you could use `accumulate` on the lengths too.

Comment: @DSM -- Right.  I missed the part about indices ... Not sure about a good way to cleanly get that ...

Answer (score 0):

```
str="aaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc"
p = [0] 
for i, c in enumerate(zip(str, str[1:])):
    if c[0] != c[1]:
        p.append(i + 1)
print p

# [0, 5, 19]
```